# Move div as content is added via PHP

Tags: html, css

In my site there are multiple blog posts, users are able to add comments to the bottom of these blog posts. When a user adds comments the content below the comment is not moving down to accommodate it and so the comment is being placed over other content. How can I solve this?

Sample idea of code:

```
<div class=blogPost>
  <article>
    <p>Blog Entry</p>
    <div id="commentsHolder">
    </div>
  </article>
  <div class="commentForm">
    <?php showing form if user is logged in ?>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=blogPost>
  <article>
    <p>Blog Entry</p>
    <div id="commentsHolder">
    </div>
  </article>
  <div class="commentForm">
    <?php showing form if user is logged in ?>
  </div>
</div>
...etc...
```

CSS:

```
.blogPost {
  position: relative;
  height: 730px;
  width: 950px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #A62121;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

When comments are added to `commentsHolder` I need the rest of the page to move down to accommodate the new comment. Let me know if you need any specific code I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing

```
height: 730px;
```

with

```
min-height: 730px;
```

in your CSS rule. It will scale the `.blogPost` as content gets added to it. It assumes that `#commentsHolder` is also relatively positioned.

You also don't want to add elements with duplicate `id` attribute (commentsHolder).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, very simple fix that has worked beautifully! Also the `id` attribute isn't duplicated in my actual code, that was just a copy paste mistake.